# Chinese grammar: type of word that is not a part of syntax analysis

Tags: grammar, syntax

I remember my teacher giving an official name for words that are not a part of syntax analysis or not being considered in syntax analysis.

For example:
如果把义放在后而把利摆在前 "If you put justice last and put profit first"

In a syntax analysis what would you call 如果?

Comment: anyhow call 如果 a conjunction （连词）

Comment: thx! that was the word i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

**如果** is a **conjunction** meaning "in the event of", the same as **if** in English.